# Finding point perpendicular to two intersecting lines in 3D

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, geometry

I have two lines `(L1, L2)` in 3D.

`L` has the following starting and ending coordinates : `P1(x1, y1, z1)` and `P2(x2, y2, z2)`.

`L2` has `P3(x3, y3, z3)` and `P2(x2, y2, z2)`. Notice how both `L1`'s and `L2`'s `P2` are same: meaning they intersect at this specific point.

Now I want to find a point `P(x,y,z)` at any distance from P2 that line `(P,P2)` is perpendicular to plane on which points `(P1,P2,P3)` are placed.

Comment: what do you mean by point perpendicular to line? that does not make any sense to me ...(point has no direction so it can not be perpendicular to anything)

Comment: To elaborate: Such a point that is EXACTLY above/below `P2` _AND_ the `PLANE` that `L1` and `L2` make. Then the line that `P2` and the `new point` make will be perpendicular to the `PLANE`

Comment: That is much clearer. I edited your question to match it but may need a bit better formulation then mine (for example find endpoint point for line (P?,P2) so it is perpendicular to plane formed by P1,P2,P3 ....). Also the title should be a bit different to avoid further confusion for others (even if the question is already answered) and possible down/close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product is the way of calculating perpendicularity relative to your two lines. You need to make vectors of your line parameters, simples way would be this:

```
vecL1 = (x1-x2, y1-y2, z1-z2) and
vecL2 = (x3-x2, y3-y2, z3-z2)
```

Cross product you can google how to calculate, but in this scenario:

```
//Replacing the new x,y,z's with i, j, k to avoid naming confusion.
vecL3 = vecL1 x vecL2 = (j1*k2 - j2*k1, k1*i2 - k2*i1, i1*j2 - j1*i2)
```

Now the cross product per definition is a new vector (line) that is strictly perpendicular to the two lines/vectors you used to calculate this with. But vectors lack position, so you need to add the intersection point to this vector in order to find some point.

```
//i3, j3, k3 being the third vector's parameters
P3(i3+x2, j3+y2, k3+z2)
```

PS: The distance from your P2 to P3 is per definition (how cross products work) to the area of a parallelogram that the two lines are sides of, I found a link to illustrate:
[image: Cross product]

Normalizing the 3rd vector will make the distance equal to 1 from P2.

Comment: I will accept your answer after you change the Cross Product formula to `vecL3 = vecL1 x vecL2 = (k2*j1 - j2*k1, k1*i2 - i1*k2, i1*j2 - j1*i2)`

Comment: @MohammadSohaib Thanks for spotting that :P

Answer (score 1):

The [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) will give you a perpendicular vector to the plane described by two other vectors, in pseudo-code:

```
normal = cross(normalize(P1-P2), normalize(P3-P2))
```

Since you've defined `P2` as the point of intersection, you can simply add this normal vector to `P2` to get your perpendicular point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any line **AB** then an arbitrary point **C** will always be perpendicular to **AB** IFF triangle **ABC** has no angle larger than π/2

That means there will always be a point **D** on line **AB** such that **CD** is perpendicular to **AB**